# Simplify roots in sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math

I have the following code in sympy

```
from sympy import *
x,y,G=symbols('x y G')
G=x**(3./2.) - y
g_inv=solve(G, x)
if len(g_inv)>1: g_inv=g_inv[-1]
dginvdy=diff(g_inv, y)
```

The problem is that this gives me

```
     ____
  3 ╱  2 
2⋅╲╱  y  
─────────
   3⋅y
```

and not `2*y**(-1./3)/3` as I expected. I have tried `simplify()` and even `cancel()` but no luck. Also, if I define the variables with `real=True` I can't invert it with `solve`for some reason. If I define only `y`as being real I get

```
2⋅sign(y)
─────────
  3 _____
3⋅╲╱ │y│
```

which is closer (?) but still not what I want. Defining `y` as positive also didn't do the trick.

This may seem like something silly but it tremendously complicates the calculations I do from then on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `sympy.factor` here rather than `simplify`:

```
In [2]: dginvdy
Out[2]: 2*(y**2)**(1/3)/(3*y)
In [3]: factor(dginvdy)
Out[3]: 2/(3*y**(1/3))
```

The [`sympy` docs](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/simplification.html) go into some detail about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that my root simplification headaches are often alleviated by defining my variables with the assumption `positive=True`, and indeed this method gets you to your desired answer here too.  You'll need to get rid of your if statement and use `g_inv=solve(G, x)[0]` because `solve(...)` will now return only a single solution.  This method can lead to some loss of generality so you just need to know your problem.